Conditions for Symmetry of mixed partials
I am studying symmetry of mixed partial derivatives in multivariate calculus(Clairaut's Theorem). Wikipedia says that differentiability of first order partials implies symmetry, to which I have found a proof for. To be more precise, if a function defined in a neighborhood of a point has partial derivatives near that point and is differentiable at that point(a.k.a. twice differentiable at the point), then symmetry follows. However, wikipedia claims that this is a weaker condition than the continuity of mixed partials($f_{xy}, f_{yx}$). This seems a bit strange since usually differentiability does not imply continuity of partials. As such I have come to wonder if this claim is true, that differentiability of $f_x, f_y$ at a point implies continuity of higher order partials at that point, and if not, a valid counterexample. Also, if this claim is true, then I am wondering if the inverse is also true, or if there is a counterexample in the other way.

What do you mean by "usual theorem"? I thought differentiability of partials was sufficient enough to prove symmetry. (Hubbard & Hubbard 2015, pp. 732–733)

Edit your post to include precisely what you mean by "differentiability of partials." In the sense of a usual calculus course, this is wrong; in the appropriate more advanced setting, it is in fact correct. However, if you don't clarify this carefully, this post will not get you anywhere.

Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I am just learning elementary calculus so I am not quite familiar with "advanced settings". Not sure if there are multiple definitions of differentiability but what I mean by the term is "for a function defined in an open region, if the function is twice differentiable" then symmetry follows. This topic is discussed here

I understand. Although in this post I am questioning that very "optimality", and if Clairaut's theorem can be optimized further than continuity of higher order partials.

Well if the former(differentiability at the point of the first partials) assumes more than the latter(continuity of mixed second partials at the point), then shouldn't we be able to prove that the former implies the latter? I might be mistaken, but isn't that what we mean by "assuming more or less" in mathematical terms?

Here are several variants of the Clariaut/Schwarz theorem, each with a somewhat different hypothesis and conclusion, so you can’t really say any one version is more/less general than the other.

Theorem 1.
Let $E,Z$ be Banach spaces over the same field $\Bbb{F}\in\{\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C}\}$, let $U\subset E$ be an open set, $p\in U$ a given point, and $f:U\to Z$ a given map. If $f$ is twice (Frechet-)differentiable at $p$ then the second derivative $D^2f_p$, thought of as a bilinear map $E\times E\to Z$ is symmetric.
Corollary 1.
Let $X,Y,Z$ be Banach spaces over the same field $\Bbb{F}\in\{\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C}\}$, let $U\subset X\times Y$ be an open set, $p=(a,b)\in U$ a given point, and $f:U\to Z$ a given map. If $f$ is twice differentiable at $p$, then $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_p:X\times X\to Z, \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}\bigg|_p:Y\times Y\to Z$ are symmetric, and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\bigg|_p,\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}\bigg|_p$ induce the same bilinear map $X\times Y\to Z$.


Theorem 2.
Let $X,Y,Z$ be Banach spaces over the same field $\Bbb{F}\in\{\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C}\}$, let $U\subset X\times Y$ be an open set, $(a,b)\in U$ a given point, and $f:U\to Z$ a given map. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist at each point of $U$ and are themselves differentiable at the point $(a,b)$ (as maps $U\to\text{Hom}(X,Z)$ and $U\to\text{Hom}(Y,Z)$ respectively), then the second derivatives $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}\bigg|_{(a,b)}$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}\bigg|_{(a,b)}$ are ‘equal’ in the sense of inducing the same bilinear map $X\times Y\to Z$.


Theorem 3.
Let $X,Y,Z$ be Banach spaces over the same field $\Bbb{F}\in\{\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C}\}$, let $U\subset X\times Y$ be an open set, $(a,b)\in U$ a given point, and $f:U\to Z$ a given map. Suppose that

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist at each point of $U$,
$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}$ exist on $U\setminus\{(a,b)\}$, and have limits at $(a,b)$.

Then, $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}\bigg|_{(a,b)}$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}\bigg|_{(a,b)}$ both exist and are ‘equal’ in the sense of inducing the same bilinear map $X\times Y\to Z$.


Theorem 3.1.
Let $Z$ be a Banach space over a field $\Bbb{F}\in\{\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C}\}$, let $U\subset \Bbb{F}\times\Bbb{F}$ be an open set, $(a,b)\in U$ a given point and $f:U\to Z$ a given map. Suppose that

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exists on $U$
there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $|k|\leq \delta$, the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b+k)$ exists
$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$ exists on $U\setminus\{(a,b)\}$, and has a limit at $(a,b)$.

Then, $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(a,b)$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(a,b)$ both exist and are equal (as elements of $Z$).


Comments about the various versions:

All the proofs follow essentially the same pattern of considering the finite second difference of the function $f$ about the point in question. Then, we prove sufficiently good (meaning, little-oh of quadratic order) estimates for the second difference minus the candidate mixed/second derivative; this is accomplished by repeated use of the mean-value theorem/inequality.

Theorem 1 is what appears in Henri Cartan’s Differential Calculus (Theorem 5.1.1), and it also appears in Dieudonne’s Treatise on Analysis (8.12.1). This is an extremely important statement because it asserts symmetry of the higher (total) derivatives as multilinear maps.

Corollary 1 really is a “trivial” application of Theorem 1.

Theorem 2 (which is the natural Banach space generalization of the version that appears in Hubbard and Hubbard) is not a corollary of Corollary 1; the hypotheses are different. So, these really are separate results.

You can’t really compare the strength of theorems 2 and 3, because the assumptions are different. In Theorem 2, you assume that the first partials are differentiable (only) at $(a,b)$ but in Theorem 3, you merely assume they exist but then you ‘compensate’ this with the assumption that the mixed partials exist in a punctured neighborhood and have limits (which will certainly be the case if they’re continuous at the point $(a,b)$).

Theorem 3.1 (which is a mild generalization of the statement in baby Rudin) sounds like a specialization of Theorem 3 to $X=Y=\Bbb{F}$, but it’s not, because we’re assuming less, and I have to admit, after playing around with it for a while, I don’t see how to remove some of the assumptions in Theorem 3 in order to get a strong conclusion like in Theorem 3.1. In effect, Theorem 3 is about equality of Frechet partial derivatives, while Theorem 3.1 is about equality of Gateaux (directional) derivatives in independent directions. And as we know, without sufficient regularity assumptions, these notions are not equivalent, hence why I’m skeptical of strengthening Theorem 3 further.

Finally, while it may seem like I’m focusing only on functions of two variables, note that if you have a function of $n$ variables, then by fixing the remaining $n-2$ of them, you again recover a function of two variables, so we’re back to the versions discussed here.


So tldr: I wouldn’t bother searching for ‘optimal’ conditions of Schwarz’s theorem. All I know are sufficient conditions; I’ve never seen necessary conditions for equality of mixed partials (Theorems 2,3,3.1). Also, in about 5 years I have never had the need for these really refined statements. I have survived with Theorem 1 alone, and more often than not, the simpler version with $C^2$ functions on an open set suffices as well in practice; also there we have a nice and simple and in some respects more natural proof via Fubini’s theorem (you might object that it’s weird to bring in integrals to prove things about derivatives… but my first response to this would be that the fundamental theorem of calculus connects these two concepts. Next, as a general philosophy, integrals are better behaved and more flexible than derivatives (Fubini’s theorem holds in great generality, and we can also talk about weak derivatives and distributions and currents with the help of integration theory)).
